How to get ride of "irrefutable `if let` pattern" warning for Mutex locking in Rust?
I want to create a small scope through the 'if let' statement when using Mutex so that it can be unlocked as quickly as possible. But I got "irrefutable if let pattern" warning when compiling. Is there a more appropriate way to write it?
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main()
{
    let sources = Mutex::new(vec![1,2,3]);
    // this get warning: irrefutable `if let` pattern
    if let mut vec = sources.lock().unwrap() {
        vec.push(4);
    };

    // No deadlock will occur here
    let mut vec = sources.lock().unwrap();
    vec.push(5);

    // deadlock will occur here, so I'd like the mutex guard dropped as quickly as possible.
    let mut vec2 = sources.lock().unwrap();
    vec2.push(6);
}


You could just explicitly drop(vec); when you're done with it.

Use a plain block:
{
    let mut vec = sources.lock().unwrap();
    vec.push(4);
}

Or, if you don’t need the variable (for readability or otherwise), you can take advantage of the drop scope of the mutex guard temporary:
sources.lock().unwrap().push(4);

